# ¿Intento poner una imagen en un JLable y a veces no funciona?

Tags: java

Hice un programa que debe poner una imagen aleatoria desde una carpeta y ponerla en un JLabel pero a veces la imagen sale bien y a veces sale estirada o aplastada. Las imágenes son más grandes que el JLable asi que tengo que modificarles el tamaño y supongo que ahi esta el problema pero no se cómo solucionarlo. Aquí el código de la función que hace eso:

```
private void ponerImagen() {
    numeroDeImagen = (int) (Math.random() * 870 + 1);
    ImageIcon imag = new ImageIcon("C:/Users/Usuario/Desktop/Imagenes/" + numeroDeImagen + ".jpg");
    int alto = imag.getImage().getHeight(this), ancho = imag.getImage().getWidth(this);

    if (alto > 1000 || ancho > 1908) {
        while (alto > 1001 || ancho > 1909) {
            alto = alto - 1;
            ancho = ancho - 1;
        }
        Image reescalada = imag.getImage().getScaledInstance(ancho, alto, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
        Icon icono = new ImageIcon(reescalada);
        uiImagen.setIcon(icono);
        uiImagen.setBounds(uiImagen.getX(), uiImagen.getY(), 1908, 1000);
    } else {
        Icon icono = new ImageIcon(imag.getImage());
        uiImagen.setIcon(icono);
        uiImagen.setBounds(uiImagen.getX(), uiImagen.getY(), 1908, 1000);
    }
    uiImagenActual.setText(numeroDeImagen + ".png");
    this.repaint();
}
```

Edit: las imágenes tienen como nombre un número y luego la extención. Por ej: 425.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Ya encontré el problema. Solo cambié el while y puse el ancho = -1. No sé porque funciona pero lo hace. El while queda asi:

```
while (alto >= 1001) {
            alto = alto - 1;
        }
        ancho = -1;
```

Bueno, además quité la parte que evalúa el ancho ya que no se necesita más.